# Setting up an user login with firebase, but got a Sigabrt on Running app

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, firebase, sigabrt

Being a person new to programming its very off putting I keep getting these Sigabrts. I would like if I knew how to fix these simple mistakes on my own, but I don't know where to begin :( I didn't even touch the AppDelegate and thats where the Sigabrt is... Hope you guys can help :)

```
2016-03-24 15:33:38.938 EXTBP[4833:289124] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<EXTBP.LoginViewController 0x7faa41443dc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key loginButton.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b2d2e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d012deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b2d2aa9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010b69b9bb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010bc7e320 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010beacf41 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b2134a0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010beab924 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010bc84eea -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010bc85816 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010bc85b74 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010bc862e7 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010bb5cab0 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010bb5d199 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010bb6ec2e -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010bae7663 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010baedcc6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1760
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010baeae7b -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010eea4754 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010eea4ac2 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b1fea31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b1f495c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b1f3e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b1f3828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010baea7cd -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010baef610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    26  EXTBP                               0x000000010af3853d main + 109
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010e45392d start + 1
    28  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: The first step in troubleshooting this is to determine which line of code is causing the crash. You should put a breakpoint(s) in your app and step through it line by line until it crashes. Then, post the code or function that is around that line of code and we can track it down from there. Sometimes you have to 'guess' as to where it may be crashing and work your way backward. So for example, the app opens a window a bit of the way into the app and then crashes. If you see the window then the crash probably happened after that point so judge where to set the breakpoint accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix you Outlets in IB [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pXIK.png)